# Latest Autofac version Doesn't support .Net Framework 4.6.2

Tags: c#, .net, autofac, .net-framework-version

My project is a cross platform project. Which contains 3 Project 2 .Net-standard 2.0 and one startup project with .Net-framework 4.6.2.

The latest Autofac version(5.2.0) is not supporting .NetFramework 4.6.2.

I have encountered the error

> autofac.core.registration.componentnotregisteredexception' in autofac.dll"
>   builder.Build() couldn't instantiate the class object.

**Error message:**

> An exception of type 'Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException' occurred in Autofac.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: The requested service 'ShipPageObjects.PageObjects.Login.LoginResolvePage' has not been registered. 
>   To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the 
>   service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), 
>   or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new ContainerConfig());
builder.RegisterInstance(testConfig).As<ITestConfig>();
builder.RegisterModule(new ShipmentmentTest(testConfig));
builder.RegisterModule(new MaterialTest(testConfig));

Container = builder.Build();
```

Comment: Can you post the entire exception stack trace?  Usually Autofac gives you the class which is causing you the issue.

Comment: There's a .NET 4.6.1 binary in the Autofac 5.2.0 nuget package, so it should be supported.

Comment: @Corv1nus I have posted the entire exception stack trace.

Comment: @Rup as i have seen other article that is why i have tried that approach. But encountering error.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what is wrong as well as how to fix it. I am not sure how you then jumped to the conclusion that it is a framework compatibility issue. Follow the advise of the exception message, that is what it is there for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an error with Autofac 5.2.0 and .NET Framework 4.6.2.  In the exception it's telling you that the `ShipPageObjects.PageObjects.Login.LoginResolvePage` is not registered.  It's likely that you're injecting it into something that you have registered and you haven't registered the LoginResolvePage.

Autofac is really good at telling you what is failing in these instances. You can either 1 by 1 go through and look at the exceptions and add as it tells you what needs added, or trace your injection back through and make sure everything is registered. I would recommend doing the latter and using the former to finish it up.

Comment: Yeah you are correct, whenever you come across builder.Build() it will instantiate the class objects. while debugging it not going through the constructor means it is not registering the objects. due to that reason I'm suspecting. same approach i have implemented in .Net core its working fine.

Comment: Autofac is working, When i'm trying to resolve resolve chromedriver in .netstandards im getting this error. Thanks